# How does Rust's protobuf crate interact with usage of Box?

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers

From experimentation, it seems like `Box<T>` works just like `T` from a protobuf standpoint.

I've changed a struct which used to contain a field of type `Option<T>` to instead contain a field of type `Option<Box<T>>`. It serializes and deserializes as expected, and also seems to be forwards/backwards compatible.

However, I haven't been able to find any documentation detailing this behavior.

Comment: Please provide a [MRE] so we can reason about it in code.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's explicitly documented, but there is precedent for it. Many popular crates implement their traits on `Box<T>` when `T` also does, for example. A well-known example of this might be serde's `Serialize` and `Deserialize` traits; you can deserialize a `Box<T>` if you could also deserialize a `T`.